# (Jquery, Ajax, Django, Cors, GET) No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header - Cors Whitelist Ignored

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, get, cors

I know this issue crops up a lot but I have yet to find a secure solution.(Note I have anonymised the urls below.)

**Problem:**

- I have set up a Apache server running Django as a restful API on serverA
- on serverB I have a simple jquery AJAX GET request
- When the request is sent I get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header"  Error but the origin is in the cors whitelist

**Notes:**

- I have installed Cors Headers in Django as per https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/
- I have added serverB's url to CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST
- If I set CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True it works fine (but insecure)
- Opening the url directly gives me the correct json response

**Code:**

Jquery on ServerB:

```
getValueWithKey : function(table, key, callback){
    uri = "serverA.com/{0}/{1}".format(table, key)
    $.ajax({
      url: uri,
      type:"GET"
      crossDomain: true,    
      dataType: 'json'
   }).done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       callback(data);
   });
},
```

Headers(As per chrome console):

```
General:
Request URL: http://serverA.com/tablename/keyname
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: serverA.com
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
Content-Type: application/json

Request Headers:
!Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://serverB.com
Referer: http://serverB.com/test.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your response header is missing the field `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *`, so you are probably not setting your cors correctly on the server side.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if it was client or server side. FYI my Solution below.

Answer (score 1):

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
)


INSTALLED_APPS = [
'corsheaders'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Thanks marin but I needed the more secure setup without CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL . FYI I found the issue which I have shown in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to change:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST=('http://example.net')
```

to

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST=('example.net')
```